# pydev download links don't work

Tags: download, pydev

I'm trying to download Pydev and having no luck at all.  I'm told to click on the link for updates, (http://www.pydev.org/updates) but I'm then sent to a "dummy" site with other links that are no help at all.  I've been at it for a couple of days now with no luck.  I have Eclipse Neon so I'm ready to go as far as that's concerned.  Anyone know what's happening and how to resolve this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's not a link you're supposed to click... you should add it as an update site in Eclipse in Help > Install New Software.

See http://www.pydev.org/download.html for a better explanation.

Comment: Well yes I know, but when I do that Eclipse tells me there's nothing there for me to use.

Comment: Humm, strange, seems to be working for me... try putting directly the url it redirects you to (right now it's https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.4.0 -- it's a redirect which always points to the latest version).

Answer (score 0):

in my eclipse it try to work with file content.xml that not exist on the link.
I try with

> jar:https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.4.0/content.jar!/

and it work to me